# No serialize access error is raised in PostgreSQL while it should be

Tags: postgresql

I have a concern about `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level behavior in a situation similar to one described below.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE concurrency_test (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    sum INT NOT NULL
);
```

Queries:

```js
+------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Step |                  Connection #1                  |                  Connection #2                  |
+------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 |                                                 | START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; |
|    2 |                                                 | INSERT INTO concurrency_test (sum) VALUES(400); |
|    3 | START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; |                                                 |
|    4 | SELECT SUM("sum") FROM concurrency_test;        |                                                 |
|    5 |                                                 | COMMIT;                                         |
|    6 | INSERT INTO concurrency_test (sum) VALUES(300); |                                                 |
|    7 | COMMIT;                                         |                                                 |
+------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

At `Step 4`, the `SELECT` query cannot see the new row inserted by another transaction because it hasn't been committed yet. So the following `INSERT` query at `Step 6` is relying on stale data.

I expected that the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level would resolve this and wouldn't allow me to successfully commit the transaction at `Step 7` and return `40001` error... But to my surprise, it did **not** raise any error.

Why did it happen and how can I achieve the behavior that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT` in step 4 does *not* rely on stale data, because the modification has not been committed yet. Until a transaction commits, the database acts as if it nothing has happened yet.

This is guaranteed by the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level and all higher ones. (PostgreSQL does not allow dirty reads, so you will get this behavior even if you request the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level.)

Moreover, `SERIALIZABLE` means that the result of all transactions is guaranteed to be the same as that of some serialized execution of the transactions. And that is clearly the case here: If we serialize by executing the transaction on connection #1 before the one on connection #2, we get the same result.

It should never be necessary, but if you want to reduce concurrency by forcing a serialized execution, add the following statement immediately after each `START TRANSACTION`:

```
LOCK TABLE concurrency_test IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

Comment: If the transaction on connection #2 had been issued before the one on connection #1 then the `SELECT` in the latter transaction would have seen the new row inserted by the other transaction.
Moreover, if I replace the `INSERT` at `Step 2` with an `UPDATE ... WHERE id = <some_existing_id>` then the commit at `Step 7` fails with `40001` error. I don't understand why `INSERT` behaves differently.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake (fixed now) - of course the equivalent serial order is #1 before #2. `UPDATE` behaves differently because (different from `INSERT`) it can also read the table data, so there is no equivalent serial ordering. Note also that PostgreSQL will sometimes throw a serialization error even if the transactions would be serializable - false positives are accepted to keep the serializability checks simple enough.